# CakePHP: Using attributesof model in associations-condition

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have a table that has a "hasOne"-association to another table, but without any foreign key. So my "hasOne"-association finds the related entity with a customized finder-method:

```
$this->hasOne('HourlyRates', [
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'finder' => ['byShift' => ['userId' => '1', 'shiftBegin' => '2016-01-01']]
]);
```

My problem is, that the options for the finder have to be the attributes of the actual entity of the first table. This is the user_id of one entity and the shift-begin of one entity.

I tried

```
'finder' => ['byShift' => ['userId' => 'Shifts.user_id', 'shiftBegin' => 'Shifts.begin']]
```

But it didn't work.
So do you know, how to access the attributes of one entity in the Table-class?

Comment: we don't know how your finder is so it's hard to tell. But did you try `['userId = Shifts.user_id', 'shiftBegin  = Shifts.begin']`?

Comment: anyway are you aware that you can create associations with composite foreign keys passing an array to the `foreignKey` and `targetForeignKey` keys?